# Page reload from controller rails 3?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

I want to redirect a user to login page if his/her session is timeout. How can I redirect my user to login page if user click on any link of my web page. And link can be a ajax call or page reload call.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily achieve that using the before_filter functionality in your controller...

These filter will check for the valid session and if it expires...redirect the user to the login page...One can also check for the Notifications API in the rails

Answer (score 0):

You should need to call the before_filter function in your controller.

You need to add this line in your controller like,

```
Class NAMEsController < ApplicationController
before_filter :authenticate_user!
```

For this you need to make sure that you installed the 'device' gem in your project.

(or)

Instead of calling `before_filter :authenticate_user!` write your own function in your controller that calls `authenticate_user!`. Something like:

```
before_filter :logged_in

private
def logged_in
  your_function
  authenticate_user!
end
```

For ajax calls, You'll need to roll your own a bit. Try this as a starting point.

```
 before_filter :login_required, :only => [:index]

 before_filter(:only => :index) do |controller|
   login_required unless controller.request.format.js?
 end
```

and you need to do some custom testing scripts. Its just an idea to sort out. I am not sure Whether its working perfectly.

Comment: I guess you ain't read requirements carefully. You approach will not work for ajax links.